# make div follow finger on ios safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, touch

how can I, using touchmove, make a div follow my finger?

Comment: i know it's kind of an open question but I really do not know where to start :)

Comment: do you want to move a div within a uiwebview or move a uiwebview only containing a div on the screen?

Comment: i mean insafari, so using html5 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be too heavy an approach, but you can use [jQueryUI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/), combined with this [touch library](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/).  It works pretty smoothly on iPad, I assume it would work on iPhone as well.

With jQuery and those two libraries, you just call '.draggable' on the div you want to move.

```
$('#divToDrag').draggable();
```

There are a zillion options for jQueryUI draggable divs, but that gets you the basics.